# React - TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have `state data:[]` and I am trying to set the values of URL in the state:

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('http://localhost:8082/seekers')
  .then( response => {
     console.log(response.data);
     this.setState({data: response.data})
})
.catch(error =>  {
 console.log(error);
});
}
```

When I use a map to show the data:

```
this.state.data.map((dynamicData,key)=>
<div key={id++}>
{dynamicData.name}{dynamicData.bloodtype}{dynamicData.bloodunits}
 </div>
)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

How to fix it?

Comment: can you share the entire code of this particular file.

Comment: Can you post where state is set initially (either in the constructor or as a class property)? What does the log you have `console.log(response.data);` show? If you log `this.state.data` in render, what does it show?

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that the `this.state.data` is not an array. I'd suggest you to check what type of data the returned `response` is.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the response, `response.data` might be an object.
Objects, {}, in JavaScript does not have the method .map(), it's only for Arrays, [].