# React : How to fix ' Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function" error even I can successfully log data to console from the API. 
I have found similar questions but, haven't come up with a good solution to solve this issue yet.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346945/11562978) that,  "Objects, {}, in JavaScript does not have the method .map(), it's only for  Arrays, []." 
However, I can not figure out how to fix this issue, iterate over an object and retrieve data to the React front end too. 
Thank you and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class GetSubjects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getsubjects = this.getsubjects.bind(this);
    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      keyword: "",
      data: []
    };
  }
  getsubjects(e) {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value });
  }
  onSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchsub = {
      keyword: this.state.keyword
    };
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/messages/courses/${this.state.keyword}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
      });
    console.log(this.state.keyword);
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label>Course Name</label>{" "}
          <input
            placeholder="Enter Course Name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.keyword}
            onChange={this.getsubjects}
            name="keyword"
            required
          />{" "}
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onSearch}>
            Get Subjects
          </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Course Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Subjects</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.data.map(function(subject) {
              return (
                <tr>
                  {" "}
                  <td key={subject.id}>{subject.name}</td>{" "}
                  <td key={subject.id}>{subject.subjects}</td>{" "}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So `this.state.data` is an array or object?

Comment: You might want to post what `console.log(response);` outputs. I guess data is an object and not an array. To tell you how to handle the data we must know how it looks like. `Object.entries(data)`, `Object.keys(data)` or `Object.values(data)` might help

Comment: @sventschui - Or better yet, set a breakpoint on the `setState` call. Rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, it's generally better to *turn on the lights* with the debugger.

Comment: JSON : ```{"subjects":["Computer Architecture","Basic Networking"],"_id":"5cf368bfb58f8c35bc19cebc","name":"Software Engineering","passmark":75,"lectureIncharge":"John Smith","__v":0}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said what you're receiving is:

```
{
    "subjects": ["Computer Architecture", "Basic Networking"],
    "_id": "5cf368bfb58f8c35bc19cebc",
    "name": "Software Engineering",
    "passmark": 75,
    "lectureIncharge": "John Smith",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Your `setState` call sets `data` to that object, which is not an array.

Your `render` code expects that to be an array, though. It tries to loop through it and use it to fill in rows in a table. But you're only getting one piece of data: A **single** course (`"Software Engineering"`) which covers two subjects (`"Computer Architecture"` and `"Basic Networking"`).

So your `render` code shouldn't be trying to use that as an array (and so you may not want a table anymore). It should just use `data`'s `name` and `subjects` properties directly.

I'll keep your table markup for now, but note that this only produces a single row (because there's only one piece of data). Prior to the `return`, I'd grab the course:

```
const course = this.state.data;
```

then where you're outputting your table:

```
<tbody>
  {course && course.name
  ? undefined
  :
  <tr>
    <td key={course.id}>{course.name}</td>{" "}
    <td key={course.id}>{course.subjects.join(", ")}</td>{" "}
  </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

I've used an explicit `join(", ")` to join the subjects rather than implicitly via `toString`, which wouldn't include a space after the comma.

Comment: @HNavanjani - I'd slightly misread what your `render` was doing with the data. I've updated the answer.

Comment: As you've stated, I've _removed_ `table` and used `join(", ")` to render. That resulted as `Computer Architecture, Basic Networking` and this is the excepted behavior; outputs subjects for a entered course perfectly :) Thank you very much for your effort and assistance !

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is an object which `axios` fills when the request is done.
It's true you're initializing `data` as an array, but when you do:
`this.setState({ data: response.data });` You've actually changed it to an object.

Parse the object you get to an array or do something else with the returned data.

**Edit**: After you response: just do: `this.setState({data: response.data.subject});`

Answer (score 0):

```js
//yo lo solucione poniendo data.data
//porque (data) solo me devolvía un objeto con varios atributos y data era uno de esos
//entonces le agregue data.data.
getCategorias(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/categorias")
            .then(data => {   
            this.setState({
                    data: data.data
                });
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.error(error)
            });
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getCategorias();
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Thanks for your answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer doesn't explain what it achieves or how it solves the problem from the original poster (OP). Please add commentary explaining what it achieves. Additionally, your comments explaining your code snippet are not in English. Please see the [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) to understand why this should be in English.